# Getting NULL when trying to get value of a button

Tags: php, html

I've got a query that outputs the contents of an SQL table. At the end of every row, I've got a button, that contains the ID of that specific row:

```
<button name='delButton' type='submit' class='delete' value='".$row["id"]."'>Delete Account</button>
```

So, the problem that I encounter is when I try to use $_POST["delButton"] to get the ID of that row, it shows as being NULL.

```
var_dump($_POST["delButton"]);
```

Comment: Also, if I use Inspect Element and check the value of the button, it shows the correct ID, but for some reason, I cannot get it using PHP

Comment: `HTML` input tag `<input type="hidden" name="delButton" value="<?php echo $row["id"];?>" />` is better approach to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an INPUT tag and get the value of that. A button's "value" is just the text on the button and is not included in the POST variables.

Comment: Ok, but that modifies the HTML text of the button, I don't want it to show the ID, but "Delete account", how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with the `name` attribute -

`<input type='submit' name='delButton[".$row["id"]."]' class='delete' value='Delete Account' />`

And then check for `isset($_POST['delButton'])` and if it is grab the key via a `foreach`, then process.